# HasOne and HasAndBelongsToMany Not Saving

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, save, has-one

I shall start with the structure of my tables. I have a Contacts table that is linked with a Tutors table using a hasOne relationship. The Tutors table is linked with a Disciplines table using HABTM relationship with Disciplines_Tutors as the join table. Now, I have both the Contacts and Tutors attributes all in one unified contact form. Same goes for the Disciplines table attribute. What happens is that I am able to save contacts and tutors into their respective tables but I am not able to save into the Disciplines_Tutors join table.

Below is the tables structure for easier understanding:

[image: Tables Structure]

This problem is not present if saving from the Tutors add form. It saves perfectly.

Contacts table has: id, its own attributes
Tutors table has: id, its own attributes, contact_id
Disciplines table has: id, discipline
Disciplines_Tutors table has: id, discipline_id, tutor_id

In the unified contact form, I am able to view the disciplines available and can make selections. But when saving, it does not save to the join table.

Tutor Model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Discipline' => array(
        'className' => 'Discipline',
        'joinTable' => 'disciplines_tutors',
        'foreignKey' => 'tutor_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'discipline_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Discipline Model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tutor' => array(
        'className' => 'Tutor',
        'joinTable' => 'disciplines_tutors',
        'foreignKey' => 'discipline_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'tutor_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

DisciplinesTutor Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Tutor' => array(
        'className' => 'Tutor',
        'foreignKey' => 'tutor_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Discipline' => array(
        'className' => 'Discipline',
        'foreignKey' => 'discipline_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

The ContactsController has:

```
    $disciplines = $this->Contact->Tutor->Discipline->find('list');
```

in the public function add section. Thus, making the retrieval of the selection list possible.

The Tutors, Disciplines, DisciplinesTutors controllers are all utilising the saveAll method.

In the add form for the unified Contact form. It has:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Tutor.Discipline',array('type'=>'select','multiple'=>true));
```

which allows me to retrieve the list of disciplines to choose from.

I am not sure what other information is needed. Feel free to ask and I will add them to this question.

Also, please be easy on me as I am quite new to CakePHP.

Thank you!

Comment: What code you have written to save associated records?

Comment: @ArunJain I have used saveAll to save the records.
`public function add() {
  if(!empty($this->data)){

   if ($this->Contact->saveAll($this->data)){
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contact has been saved'));
     $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else{
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contact could not be saved. Please try again.'));
   }
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `'deep' => true` option with the saveAll() Method to save multiple associated records. You can try the following code to save multiple associated data:

```
 $this->Contact->saveAll($this->data, array('deep' => true));
```

You can also try it using [saveAssociated()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) method.

It will work only if you are receiving the same array as you are getting the result while selecting any contact through `find()` method.

Comment: Hi, I have used 
`$this->Contact->saveAll($this->data, array('deep'=>true))`  
but it still does not work.

Comment: It will work only if you are receiving the same array as you are getting the result while selecting any contact through `find()` method.

Comment: Im sorry. I dont get it. 
I have this:
`$disciplines = $this->Contact->Tutor->Discipline->find('list');

$this->set(compact('disciplines'));`
  
Do I have to do anything with it?

Comment: Changing it to this: 
`$disciplines = $this->Contact->Tutor->Discipline->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Discipline.discipline')));
$this->set(compact('disciplines'));` doesnt help either

Comment: deep option does not work with save(), only with saveAll and friends and is only available from 2.1

Comment: Yes Ceeram. Thanks. I edited my answer. That was typo error, I realized.